# Can an action be mirrored?

Tags: animation

Is there a way to mirror actions that were keyed for one side to be mirrored to the other side?

[image]

I tried to add another x-flipped action as the button (green 1) does for the current pose. 
This button is only available in the pose editor.

Then I tried to copy and paste key-frame by frame (from green 2 to red 3) but it seems that we can't have two different views of the action editor. (When the selected action is changed in one action editor the other one copies the change and displays the same action)

How can an action be x-flipped mirrored into another action?

Comment: For current readers in 2016 and Blender 2.77 there is a button in the action editor to flip the pose or equivalently flip the pose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Copy/Paste operators in Action Editor, which supports multiple keyframes:

[image]

- Select keyframes, then press the "copy to buffer" Button on the header, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.
- Switch to another action, keep the current frame marker unchanged, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.
- Right click on the first frame you want to flip, turn on auto-keyframe on Timeline header, hover the mouse cursor in 3D View, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, to "overwrite" the existing action on that frame, for the following keyframes, you just repeat by <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to flip action on each keyframe one by one continuously. (For large number of keyframes, you may consider to make a small macro for the repeated operation to speed it up a lot).

Answer (score 11):

To extend Leon Cheung's answer (my reputation isn't high enough to comment yet), you can achieve the same thing by selecting ALL of the keyframes from the Action Editor (press <kbd>A</kbd>) and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste the flipped animation somewhere else. This works for the WHOLE animation, and can save more time than doing it manually (and is a whole lot less error prone).

Answer (score 5):

*Key > Mirror > By Times over current frame* does an X-flip based on the timeline cursor. If you place the cursor at the center of the keyframed range, it will flip in-place.

You may also use *Key > Transform > Scale* and type `-1`.

Comment: Thanks, this is also useful but it reverses the movement, a forward steps is turned to a backward step but it won't flip from left to right side.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your goal

Comment: is this in dope or action view? it doesn't from left to right arm

Answer (score 3):

You want to flip the pose position of one side of your armature. You do that in Pose mode, from the Pose menu in the 3D viewer. Highlight the bones you want to mirror the pose of, then go into the Pose menu and select Copy Pose. Now highlight the bones you want to copy the pose to (at the desired frame) and select Paste X Flipped Pose.

Comment: That did it for me. If you want to mirror all the bones at once, you can even select all the bones `Right click > Copy Pose`, then while keeping the same bones selected, `Right-click > Paste X Flipped Pose`