# How can I flip the direction of an animation

Tags: animation

Hi Im starting to learn how to animate in blender. I made a simple walkcycle animation but i want to add the same animation into another action where my character walks in the other direction. I tried to just simply rotate the rigged model and did set all the keyframes but that changed also the direction of my other actions.
Example of the idea: action 1: walkingcycle in left direction
                     action 2: SAME walkingcycle in right direction

Thanks for taking your time to read through.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your animation to an action strip in NLA Editor and use strip's properties to reverse animation:

[image: flip_1]

Note that after this conversion you won't be able to edit your animation, i.e change keyframes' position or add new ones. So you may want to create backup of your mesh with editable animation.

Comment: beat me to it :D

Comment: @MrZak I think he meant mirroring the animation on some axis, reversing will not make the rig turn left or right.

Comment: @Denis yes thats what i meant. He is walking backwards now but that was not what i wanted XD.

Comment: well, I misread your question. Then it seems to be [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7061/can-an-action-be-mirrored) can help you ?

Comment: I already tried that one. It only mirrors/flips the animation without the amature. Isn't there a way to rotate the amature without affecting the animations?

Comment: @George yes that's a bit difficult to accomplish since you need to mirror the location and rotation of the root, I'm sure there is an addon for that.

Comment: I heard about [this](http://www.scio.de/de/blog-a-neues/scio-development-blog/entry/flip-animation-add-on-for-mirroring-keyframes-in-blender) addon, but it seems it isn't up to date for now

Comment: That addon is not compatible with the new versions of blender, this is the only addon that I know of that does the job but it cost 15$ http://blog.machinimatrix.org/sparkles/

Comment: This is [the only thing](http://i.imgur.com/ycH4Ae4.gif) I can think of. That addon from scio.de worked for me (sort of), but did nothing (0 pasted, 0 deleted, though telling it did something) so I think it's really no longer a way

Comment: Thank you all for your effort! Nothing really worked the way i wanted it to but i guess you can't fix anything :/. Thanks again!

Comment: @George sparkles addon works perfectly

Comment: looks like this video shows a simple way to do it. simply change the x scale to -1 at the armature objetct properties and apply deltas (ctrl + a and choose "all transforms to deltas")
https://youtu.be/oKGWD65wqxo?si=dhs7YS6q-583poXS